# react-apollo with typescript stopped working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo

I have huge problems with apollo-react and typescript. For some reason compiling started fail (I don't what has changed). I started from the clean table couple of times but no luck. Here is the error, looks very clear but I'm not able resolve it.

```
.../node_modules/react-apollo/ApolloConsumer.d.ts
(1,8): Module '.../node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no default export.
```

This appears when I include ApolloProvider.

I have tried with allowSyntheticDefaultImports and esModuleInterop flags but it just get new problems and also I'm sure earlier it worked without.

-hakki

Comment: I don't know what happened before, but you do need to enable `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` (or `esModuleInterop`, which implies it) for this import to work.  Please enable it and add the new problems you get to the question so we can troubleshoot those.

Comment: Well, is asked me 'npm install @types/lodash' what I did... and then I got """..../node_modules/react-apollo/browser.d.ts
(17,36): Module '"..../node_modules/@types/lodash/flowRight"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be"""

Comment: But I still believe that it was working earlier without allowSyntheticDefaultImports/esModuleInterop flags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you enable `esModuleInterop`, it looks like the `react-apollo/browser.d.ts` breakage was introduced recently by [this PR](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/pull/2332) (released in version 2.2.0) and fixed today by [this PR](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/pull/2430) (not yet released).  You'll have to go back to `react-apollo` version 2.1.11 (or point your dependency to the git repository) until the fix is released.

Comment: Miracle... I installed apollo dependencies again as you proposed `npm i apollo-boost graphql react-apollo@2.1.11 -S` and things started to work. And actually it works now without `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` flags. So I guess I updated version in some point and everything stopped working. Thanks!